# Python noob, need help improving program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python coding, i need a program that will show current CPU temperature. My CPU have 4 cores, so i made following program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import re

sensor_data = subprocess.check_output('/usr/bin/sensors')

find_temp = re.search(r'Core 0:\s+\+([\d]+).*', sensor_data)

if find_temp:
    core_0_temp = find_temp.groups()[0]
else:
    core_0_temp = 0

find_temp = re.search(r'Core 1:\s+\+([\d]+).*', sensor_data)

if find_temp:
    core_1_temp = find_temp.groups()[0]
else:
    core_1_temp = 0

find_temp = re.search(r'Core 2:\s+\+([\d]+).*', sensor_data)

if find_temp:
    core_2_temp = find_temp.groups()[0]
else:
    core_2_temp = 0

find_temp = re.search(r'Core 3:\s+\+([\d]+).*', sensor_data)

if find_temp:
    core_3_temp = find_temp.groups()[0]
else:
    core_3_temp = 0

print core_0_temp, core_1_temp, core_2_temp, core_3_temp
```

Can anyone give some suggestion on how to improve this program ?

Currently it works, but what can i do to improve this code ?

```
boby@fwhlin:~/utils/cpu$ ./cpu_temp 
49 48 48 46
boby@fwhlin:~/utils/cpu$
```

Result of sensors command is given below

```
boby@fwhlin:~/utils/cpu$ /usr/bin/sensors
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:       +0.93 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.60 V)
+3.3V Voltage:       +3.28 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+5V Voltage:         +5.14 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
+12V Voltage:       +12.03 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU Fan Speed:      2721 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
Chassis1 Fan Speed:    0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
Chassis2 Fan Speed:    0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
NB Fan Speed:       1318 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
Power Fan Speed:       0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CPU Temperature:     +56.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
MB Temperature:      +60.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +75.0°C)
NB Temperature:      +56.5°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +57.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

boby@fwhlin:~/utils/cpu$
```

Comment: Better post it on [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What kind of improvement you want?

Comment: Serially named variables (`core_1`, `core_2`) is usually an indication that you actually want a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can put it in a for loop, and use a dict/list to store the values:

```
core_temps = {}
for core in range(4):
    find_temp = re.search(r'Core %d:\s+\+([\d]+).*' % core, sensor_data)
    if find_temp:
        core_temps[core] = find_temp.groups()[0]
    else:
        core_temps[core] = 0
print core_temps
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import re

sensor_data = subprocess.check_output('/usr/bin/sensors')

find_temps = re.finditer(r'Core (\d*):\s+\+([\d]+).*', sensor_data)

temps = {}
for find_temp in find_temps:
    index, temp = find_temp.group(1, 2)
    temps[index] = temp

print temps
for k in sorted(temps.keys()):
    print k, temps[k]
print
```

This searches for all `Core XX:` lines and puts them into a dict.